# Asymptotic expansion of functions

Tags: calculus

Find the leading term in the asymptotic expansion of the following function as x → + ∞  $$
\int_0^{\pi}\cos(x(t-\sin(t)))dt
$$

Comment: Please.Its urgent.

Comment: 1.) Be polite: Ask, don't demand!
2.) Learn  $Tex$ to write readable question
3.) Show your own efforts

Comment: I try. This is my first time. I dont know to write readable. But i will learn as soos as possible.

Comment: This is the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).